# How do I format a BigDecimal to only show as many decimal digits as needed?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formatting

I have a BigDecimal that has either 0, 1 or 2 decimal digits (I'm calling round(2) on it). I want to display it in a view in such a way that it'll only show as many decimal digits as needed. In other words:

```
 7.0 -> "7"
 7.5 -> "7.5"
 7.67 -> "7.67"
```

How do I achieve this? So far, it's showing "7.0" instead of "7".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your views, look at the methods from the NumberHelper, in particular the `number_with_precision`, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision

Particularly, you want the strip_insignificant_zeros option.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need Ruby on Rails when you have the geeky magic of [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
[7.0, 7.5, 7.57].map{ |f| "%g" % BigDecimal.new(f,3) }
#=> ["7", "7.5", "7.57"]
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of `BigDecimal` because the `"%g"` in `sprintf` will convert it to a float, losing the precision.